# Auth error trying to connect to Gmail from C# app, but no security alert email

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, mailkit

I'm building a prototype web site to show a client, and need to connect to Gmail to access emails. For simplicity (as this is a prototype) I am trying to connect using the email and password for a throwaway Gmail account I created. Full security will come later, when we (hopefullly) get the agreement for the full app.

I'm using Mailkit, and the code is as follows...

```
  ImapClient client = new();
  await client.ConnectAsync("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
  await client.AuthenticateAsync(userName, password);
```

The first time I tried this from my local machine, the auth failed, and a "Security alert" email was sent to the Gmail account saying that a new device had tried to log in. It gave me the option to check the activity, and confirm that the new device was actually me.

After that, I was able to run the code from my local machine without problem.

Another developer just checked out my changes and tried it on his machine, and got an auth failed exception. Understandable, as his device hasn't been used for this before. However, this time, the Gmail account didn't receive a "Security alert" email, so he had no way of telling Google that his device was to be trusted.

I then deployed the site to a test server, and had the same problem.

Anyone any idea why we don't get a "Security alert" email for the other dev's machine or for the test server? More to the point, any idea how we tell Google to trust these two devices? I don't have the resources to add OAuth to this prototype at this stage.

The Imap log is shown below.

Thanks

**Imap log**

```
Connected to imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/
S: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 185.160.182.96 n14mb29765764wrp
C: A00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
S: A00000000 OK Thats all she wrote! n14mb29765764wrp
C: A00000001 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN AG5vd2l0c21pbmUyMDIwQGdtYWlsLmNvbQBIZXl5b3VBbmRtZTEy
S: * NO [WEBALERT https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsNd6RU3LIlgDfhmL9Y7ywYhtagFig_xfuSJCUHD9Eg3XqN8DKlDk3G8jmj2w5viIm5PDC3BS4SVy7iFMB6g1244cnQt1E60EdOTSEpnqDzL6FH2L-ReOAyZ3qkSXZQZs2pIfL2] Web login required.
S: A00000001 NO [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail has this security feature where it requires you to login first via a web browser on the machine before it will let you connect via IMAP.

You might be able to work around this by going to the gmail settings and creating a app-specific password for your app to use.

Also, MailKits FAQ has a section about what settings to change in order to allow “less secure apps” to authenticate. Not sure if you did those steps yet.

Can you also file a feature request for MailKit to add support for Gmail’s [WEBALERT …] response code? From a quick glance, I think that may be something MailKit could parse and emit an event for (not that it would help your app that much in this case, but maybe useful to have anyway?)

Comment: Thanks for the great support as ever! I did enable less secure apps, which is how I got it to work in the first place. As it happens, it turned out that implementing OAuth wasn't as painful as I thought, so I decided to go down that route instead. However, I'll put in that feature request anyway. Thanks again.